# How to register user using xmpp/jabber in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, xmpp, chat, ejabberd

iPhone Chat app using xmpp/jabber.
This method i am not able register on server. it gives me "403" error.
Can anyone help me, how can i create a new account on server using xmpp/jabber in ios?

here my code :

```
 NSString *username = loginField.text;
    NSString *password = passwordField.text;


    AppDelegate *del = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    del.xmppStream.myJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:username];

    NSLog(@"Does supports registration %hhd ",del.xmppStream.supportsInBandRegistration );


    NSLog(@"Attempting registration for username %@",del.xmppStream.myJID.bare);

    if (del.xmppStream.supportsInBandRegistration)
    {
        NSError *error = nil;

        if (![del.xmppStream registerWithPassword:password error:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Oops, I forgot something: %@", error);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"No Error");
        }
    }
```

and i got error

ERROR :-

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="username@Testlocalhost" to="username@Testlocalhost/40751035661420464079722458" type="error">
    <query xmlns="jabber:iq:register">
    <username>newusername</username>
    <password>userpassword</password>
    </query>
    <error code="403" type="auth">
    <forbidden xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
    </error>
    </iq>
```

Comment: Are you sure your server side xmpp is set up correctly?

Comment: @Janmenjaya thank for the comment. Please Guide me , how should i check server side XMPP setup? Is there any command please Advice

Comment: Please check these links which guides you how to set up own xmpp server using openfire.
http://macs.about.com/od/diyguidesprojects/ss/Create-Your-Own-Jabber-Based-Server_2.htm

http://www.tecmint.com/create-your-own-instant-messagingchat-server-using-openfire-in-linux/

http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/


And yes, if you want to check your xmpp code is correct or not then use your gmail id and gtalk server. You can set domain name in "goOnline" method of xmpp framework. I hope it will help you